# Adding and removing objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am implementing a shopping cart project on an iPad.

I have a class "productItem"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ProductItem : NSObject

+(instancetype)createProductId:(NSString *)aId description:(NSString *)aDesc price:(int)aPrice;
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString *productId;
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString *description;
@property(nonatomic)int price;

@end
```

A class "CartItem"

> @interface CartItem : NSObject
>
> @property(nonatomic,weak)ProductItem *prodItem;
>   @property(nonatomic)int quantity;
>
> +(instancetype)createProdItem:(posProductItem *)aProdItem quantity:(int)aQuantity;
>
> @end

I have another class "ProductStore". This class has 2 NSMUtableAray that stores productItems and cartItems:

```
@property(nonatomic)NSMutableArray *productItems;
@property(nonatomic)NSMutableArray *cartItems;
```

I implemented 2 ViewControllers, productSearchViewController and cartViewController. The cartViewController basically displays the elements in cartItems.

The functionalities of productSearchViewController are describe below:

**productSearchViewController**

- products are displayed in UICollectionView. ProductItems retrieved from the web service are populated into ProductStore NSMutableArray "productItems"
- Product Items can be added into "cartItems".

> [CartItem createProdItem:aProdItem quantity:1]; // here aProdItem is ProductItem *

- User can search for product in UISearchBar. I implemented `(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)searchText` to query the web service for data. For each search, I will clear NSMutableArray "productItems" and re-populate it with the data from web service

Because I clear UIMutableArray "productItems", the productItem in NSMutableArray "cartItems"  gets deleted too. The cartItem elements are still there but the productItem in each cartItem element are empty: Product id, description and price are empty.

How should i go about solving this problem? should I copy ProductItem object into CartItems when a product is added into shopping cart?

Comment: Use a strong property for `prodItem`.

Comment: hi Hot Licks, tks for the reply. that works.

Comment: But see Murat's answer -- what you're doing doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prodItem` is set to `nil` because you have declared it as a `weak` property in `CartItem` in the following line:

```
@property(nonatomic,weak)ProductItem *prodItem;
```

You should use a `strong` property if you need to use it in the `CartItem` class even though it is removed from the `productItems` array.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)ProductItem *prodItem;
```

Although this should solve your problem, it does not actually make much sense to clear the productItems but keep the cartItems.

Comment: hi tks for replying. would creating another NSMutableArray to store the search productItems help?

Comment: On a second thought, I don't think you need two different arrays because you are clearly using `productItems` to store the items that are displayed by `productSearchViewController`. I was misled by the name of `ProductStore` class an thought `productItems` was supposed to include all items in the store.